# How to check for session null on master page without logging out

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a problem with reading value from session on every page load. I have to check if this session value is null on master page because I need to show the user real name when it's logged in so i can't rely only on forms authentication.

I'm also doing the same thing on every page load.

```
if (Session["Nome"] == null)
{
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
}
```

I'm not sure why or if it's due to slow loading but even when i'm still authenticated i get redirected to login so at some point the session is null. I was wondering if is there a better way to show user name(not username) on master page and redirect to login page when the variable is actually null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well by default `Session` variables have a time span of 20 minutes, so if you are not refreshing the variable it will be null after the time span passes. So you either have to reset the time span for the `"Nome"` variable ( not recommended as staying on one page for 21 minutes would force the user to re login after another postback ) or check

```
if(!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    FormsAuthentification.RedirectToLoginPage();
var username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: Yes this is possible but still feels unsafe without checking if the session variable is null. And I set the session timeout to 300 minutes in web config though

Comment: so why not use the second bit? it first checks if the current user is logged in and if not redirects to the login page. If he is logged in you can get the username from `HttpContext` and you won't have to use `Session`

Comment: that is the problem, I don't want to show username, but the real name I get from database and store on session after validading login

Comment: Well use the first part to actually redirect if the user is not authenticated and if he is get the name from the session variable if it is not null or get the name from database and then set the Session again.

Comment: Yes thank you, i'm so idiot i didn't think of this before. I'm using a session manager to handle session variables, and whenever it's null i get it again from database and I do this after checking if user is authenticated, works like a charm